# A 3D solid has a base region which is enclosed by parabolas $y=-x^2+1$ and $y=x^2-1$ perpendicular to the $x$-axis are rectangle. what is the volume?

Tags: calculus

A 3D solid has a base region which is enclosed by parabolas $y=-x^2+1$ and $y=x^2-1$ cross sections perpendicular to the x-axis are rectangle with heights fixed at $1$.

Follow up question: If the cross-sectional areas are semicircles. what is the volume?

Answer (score 0):

The volume is

$$
2\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2) dx=\frac 83.
$$

If the cross-sections were semicircles instead of rectangles it would be

$$
\frac\pi2\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^2 dx=\frac {8\pi}{15}.
$$

Comment: thank you! but I was also wondering if the cross-sectional areas are semi-circles? what would the volume be then?

Comment: @cchown I have added the semicircle case, assuming that the semicircles are perpendicular to the $x$-axis and cross the $xy$-plane at the parabola points.